# Integrating the derivative of a function does not give expected result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I was trying to do the following integral:

```
f[z_]:=Hypergeometric2F1[1,-a,1-a,1/(1-z)]/((1-z)^a-1)
Integrate[D[f[z],z],z]
```

I thought the result should be `f[z]` itself.  But it turns out that *Mathematica* is not able to do the integral:

[image]

Is it normal that *Mathematica* is not able to do such thing? Is there anything I can do to make it able to do the integral?

Comment: `Quiet@Integrate[Evaluate[D[f[z], z] // FullSimplify], z]`

Comment: @Dr.belisarius, I tried your command, but it's still not able to do the integral.

Comment: Dr. belisarius method works for me (*Mathematica* 10.3.1). Call the result `int`. Then evaluate `FullSimplify[int == f[z]]` and obtain output `True`,

Comment: @murray Also works here, v9

Comment: @Dr.belisarius That works for me now, thank you. I'm now trying to calculate        f[z_]:=(1-z)^a Hypergeometric2F1[1,-a,1-a,1/(1-z)]/((1-z)^a-1)
Integrate[D[f[z],z],z]. And it seems that your method doesn't work for this case.

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(*  "10.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 9, 2015)"  *)

f[z_] = Hypergeometric2F1[1, -a, 1 - a, 1/(1 - z)]/((1 - z)^a - 1);

f2[z_] = Integrate[D[f[z], z] // FullSimplify, z] // Quiet

(*  -((a*(1/(1 - z))^a*Beta[1/(1 - z), 
           -a, 0])/(-1 + (1 - z)^a))  *)

f3[z] = f2[z] // FullSimplify

(*  Hypergeometric2F1[1, -a, 1 - a, 
     1/(1 - z)]/(-1 + (1 - z)^a)  *)

f[z] == f2[z] == f3[z] // FullSimplify

(*  True  *)
```

EDIT: to address OP's question in comment. I do not know why changing the sign makes the problem harder for Mathematica; however, there is a straightforward workaround.

```
f4[z_] = -Hypergeometric2F1[1, -a, 1 - a, 1/(1 - z)]/((1 - z)^a - 1);

f5[z_] = -Integrate[D[-f4[z], z] // FullSimplify, z] // Quiet

(*  (a (1/(1 - z))^a Beta[1/(1 - z), -a, 0])/(-1 + (1 - z)^a)  *)

f6[z] = -(-f5[z] // FullSimplify)

(*  -(Hypergeometric2F1[1, -a, 1 - a, 1/(1 - z)]/(-1 + (1 - z)^a))  *)

f4[z] == f5[z] == f6[z] // FullSimplify

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: That works for me, thank you. But if I add a minus sign in f[z] (f[z_] = -Hypergeometric2F1[1, -a, 1 - a, 1/(1 - z)]/((1 - z)^a - 1)) then it does't work. Do yo know why?

Comment: @HChan - see edit above.